# Mapping of { and } does not work in chain commands like `di{`

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I mapped the following and tried with either and both mappings activated in hope to cover all vim modes:

```
map! ĸ {
map ĸ {
```

The mapping works in insert mode and in normal mode as expected, but when I try to do a command like `di{` to delete all inside a pair of braces `{}`, nothing happens. Recursive mapping works for `{` in another command that fails if I use `ino {` instead, so it must be active...

I don't understand why it doesn't work in the chained commands.

Comment: You will probably get more help at Vi Stack Exchange.

Comment: alright, will try that

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `i{` is a whole operator-pending command (or text object) and mappings don't really work for the later parts of an existing command or mapping. If you want to support `i{` (and its friend `a{`) in operator-pending and visual modes, you would need an additional set of mappings to explicitly do so:

```
omap iĸ i{
omap aĸ a{
xmap iĸ i{
xmap aĸ a{
```

But a much better way to accomplish this key mapping is to use the [`'langmap'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27langmap%27) feature, which allows you to remap keys in normal mode. For your particular use case you will also need to set `'langremap'`.

```
set langmap=ĸ{
set langremap
```

This will take care of Normal mode, Visual mode, operator-pending mode and also mappings involving the `{` symbol.

It will not take care of Insert mode or command-line mode. For that, you can either keep using a `:map!` (which typically works fine), or there's also a [`'keymap'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27keymap%27) option for the Insert mode equivalent of `'langmap'`, but `'keymap'` is considerably more complex (it involves creating a separate mapping file with unique syntax and there are a few additional options controlling where exactly the mapping is activated.)